# Rake task error: uninitialized constant == Model / Controller classes not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

In Rails 3.2.16 execution of this rake task breaks with `uninitialized constant` error, complaining that the Model class `MyModel` is not known.

```
  desc "some rake task"
  task :do_it => :environment do
    # do something depending on a model:
    MyModel.each do |m|
      # do something with model
    end
    # ...
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the root-cause of this is that I had `config.threadsafe!` enabled in the config files.

To fix this, do this:

```
  # only enable threadsafe! mode if we are not running rake tasks
  config.threadsafe! unless File.split($0).last == 'rake' # unless it's a rake task
```